# Prove $|v \times(u \times v)|=\sqrt{((u.u)(v.v)^2-(v.v)(u.v)^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Use the formula for the angle between two vectors $v$ and $u$ to show $$|v \times(u \times v)|=\sqrt{((u.u)(v.v)^2-(v.v)(u.v)^2}$$

I have endlessly used $u.v = |u||v|\cos(\theta)$ but to no avail:

This was my square root after simplifying

$$ \sqrt{\cos^3(\theta)|u|^2|v|^4-\cos^3(\theta)|v|^3|u|^2} $$

But I don't know how to continue further...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the angle formula $| u\times v| = |u| \cdot | v| |\sin(\theta )|$

Then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
| v\times (u\times v)| &&= | v| \cdot | u\times v| \\
&&= | v|^2| u||\sin(\theta)|\\
&&= | v|^2| u|\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)}\\
&&= | v|^2| u|\sqrt{1-\big(\frac{u\cdot v}{ | u| \cdot | v|}\big)^2}\\
&&= \sqrt{(u\cdot u) (v\cdot v)^2 - (u\cdot v)^2(v\cdot v)}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta$ the angle between $u$ and $v$. Since $u\times v$ is a vector orthogonal to both of $u$ and $v$ we have 
\begin{align*}
 |v\times (u\times v)| &=|v||u\times v|\\
   &=|v||u||v||\sin \theta|\\
   &=|v||u||v|\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\\
   &=|v|\sqrt{|u|^2|v|^2-(u\cdot v)^2}\\
   &=\sqrt{|u|^2|v|^4-(u\cdot v)^2|v|^2}\\
   &=\sqrt{(u\cdot u)(v\cdot v)^2-(v\cdot v)(u\cdot v)^2}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

(Note: the following is not using "*the formula for the angle between two vectors $v$ and $u$*".)

Using the [vector triple product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product)...

$$a \times(b \times c) = \langle a , c \rangle \,b - \langle a , b \rangle \,c$$

...for $\,a=v, \,b=u, \,c=v\,$ gives:

$$v \times(u \times v) = \langle v , v \rangle \,u - \langle u , v \rangle \,v$$

Then scalar multiplying both sides by themselves:

$$
\begin{align}
|v \times(u \times v)|^2 & = \left\langle \langle v , v \rangle \,u - \langle u , v \rangle \,v \;,\; \langle v , v \rangle \,u - \langle u , v \rangle \,v \right\rangle \\
 & = \langle v , v \rangle^2 \,\langle u, u\rangle - 2 \langle u , v \rangle^2 \,\langle v, v\rangle + \langle u , v \rangle^2 \,\langle v, v\rangle \\
 & = \langle v , v \rangle^2 \,\langle u, u\rangle - \langle u , v \rangle^2 \,\langle v, v\rangle
\end{align}
$$